# re-establishing interractive shell on multi-hop SSH connections

Tags: paramiko, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a use case where from host "A" I need to ssh into host "D" through hosts "B" and "C" (I'd like to be able to apply the solution to as many middle hosts as possible):

> A==>B==>C==>D

Once the connection is established to D, I’d like to run the list of commands ["comm1", "comm2", "comm3"] and receive the response as ["output1", "output2", "output3"] at host A.
The only strategy I came up with was, once you arrive to host D:

1. Perform a connection.invoke_shell()
2. Send comm1 in, poll the channel for output, collect the response and insert it into an empty list
3. Close the channel created by connection.invoke_shell()
4. Build a fresh interactive shell channel
5. Repeat steps 1 to 5 for comm2 and comm3

When I developed that realized that trying to re-establish the interactive shell channel will result in an EOFError. I’m having a hunch that closing the channel in step 3 terminates the entire SSH session all the way from host A to host D.

It is, however, imperative to close the channel and start a fresh interactive shell for every command otherwise, you'll be reading the full output of the channel (containing the output of all 3 commands) as one big block of text, which you then have to process using screen-scraping, which is not ideal.
Is the algorithm above possible? If yes how can one implement it with paramiko and why am I getting the EOFError exception?

I also tried to achieve this using Fabric. It worked with some devices but not on cisco ones. The reason is that Fabric uses ssh remote command execution feature of paramiko also which is not supported by some Cisco devices (look into client.exec_command). Therefore an interactive session was the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, consider the no-hop case:

```
$ ssh -i key user@host 'echo command; echo control'
command
control
$ ssh -i key user@host 'echo command; echo control' >/dev/null
$ ssh -i key user@host 'echo command; echo 1>&2 control' >/dev/null
control
```

In other words, we have two output channels...